# What are the correct steps to run a site as HTTPS?

Tags: 8, ssl

There is some information on https://www.drupal.org/https-information about installing the Secure Pages module to force SSL. This gives me a redirect loop on the login pages.

When I try without the Secure Login module I get mixed mode errors due to JS being served in plain http. Is a module really the only method to enable SSL on D8?

Assuming the server configuration is set-up for HTTPS and has the relevant SSL certifications and settings:
**Specifically, with the Drupal configuration, what is the correct way to make a Drupal 8 site Https only?**

Comment: If D8 cares what protocol it's served on that's got to be a pretty major bug - it was never a problem in D7, the web server just needed to be set up to forward http requests to https, base url set up correctly, and you're away. The secure login module is: _For sites that are available via both HTTP and HTTPS_, so for an "Https only" site that you're describing, it should never be installed

Comment: Looks like it is a bug. Opened a new question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186057/is-using-a-ssl-termination-proxy-currently-possible-in-drupal-8

Comment: @Clive I think base_url was removed in D8