# Is using a TLS/SSL termination reverse proxy currently possible in Drupal 8

Tags: caching, proxies, 8, ssl

I use Nginx (port 443) which terminates TLS/SSL then forwards the request to Varnish (port 80) and on to Apache (port 8080). This worked really well for D7.

Am I correct in thinking that because of the following bug this set-up cannot work without 'Mixed Content' errors due to CSS and JS being written as absolute paths rather than relative paths?

[References to CSS, JS, and similar files should be relative to server: less bytes, avoids mixed content warnings](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494670)

I am looking for conformation of this question to ensure that it is not my server configuration at fault.

Comment: I think the answer is No. I applied the patch referenced and the errors were corrected. Waiting for conformation that it couldn't be solved on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch you reference was [applied to Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494670#comment-10770526) last month. [Drupal 8.0.3](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-8.0.3-release-notes) was released 3 February and included the fix. If you're using this version (or later) you should be fine.

---